# Boolean Union not working. Subtracting instead of adding?

Tags: modifiers

Tried looking this up on google, here, etc, etc, etc.

I have pics. Plain and simple question. I'm doing a boolean union and it looks like its subtracting the target if anything. I forgot to take a picture of it, but the crescent circle I'm trying to add actually worked on the other side of the oval. That is the vexing part about this. Any ideas?

[image: BEFORE]

[image: AFTER]

Comment: Remove doubles, flip normal and then boolean

Comment: Same results...

Comment: Nevermind. Apprently it was someting wrong with one of those crescents. The one I used on the other side worked on this side as well. The flip and remove enabled that. Thanks.